# How to have server issue command to have a socket leave or join a room when running multiple-nodes

Tags: socket.io-1.0

Running `socket.io 1.0` with multiple instances.

In this use case server can receive a request (from "outside" socket.io, it's not coming on the socket) that should lead to a socket leaving or joining rooms.

I have access to socket.id, but how do I do `socket.leave` if socket may not be in same process?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to associate the socket to a channel such as a redis pub sub channel.  Your server would then publish an event onto the the channel and since your socket is subscribed to that channel it will get the message.  I am working on a project called bus.io.  It is a small framework that allows you to build event-driven distributed applications on top of socket.io and redis.

https://github.com/turbonetix/bus.io

Comment: bus.io looks pretty awesome, though a bit conerned it's hard to grok. Will try it out and spam you with a github issues if I get stuck ;)

Comment: I would appreciate any feedback on improving the product or documentation